# Split a string in UIPath using regex

Tags: regex, split

I have a string stored in a variable - "Input_value:123_Output".
I want to split this string with underscore(_) and Double colon(:). So that the indexing of my output string will be like this : [0]-Input, [1]-value, [2]-123, [3]-Output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting on the regex character class `[:-]`.  This would split on either a colon or an underscore, which is the behavior you want.

In addition to `[:-]` looking like a smiley face, it is also very compact and easy to read.